# entity framework core, generic repository method with inclusion navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, asp.net-core

I want to create a universal data access layer through a business logic project, The business logic layer must interact with the DAL layer in which I have a repository.
I want to have a short-lived data context and all the repository methods returning IEnumerable and not IQueryable.
Prompt on an example of method GetAll how I can extract the connected data through ThenInclude or Select to dependent tables.

```
public class GenericDataRepository<T> : IGenericDataRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public virtual IList<T> GetAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
    {

        List<T> list;
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();

            //Apply eager loading
            foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
                dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);

            list = dbQuery
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToList<T>();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

}

ThenInclude(prop2=>prop2.i)?

dbQuery.Include(navigationProperty).ThenInclude(prop2=>prop2.i)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually bad design. You don't want to do this. If you want to abstract your data access layer, then do so completely. Create a library that provides an API for your application, which returns exactly what you need, no more and no less. If you're going to still allow arbitrary querying, then just utilize your context directly, as you're not actually buying yourself anything other than an additional layer to maintain, with no real benefit.

Comment: Thank you.
I wanted to create an api for accessing data, it uses a layer of business logic. In the future, it is possible to replace the EF with a dapper, leaving the EF only for migrations. I understand  you advise working with IGureble in the layer, the business logic? Abstracted from the data access layer, I want a layer of business logic.
business logic-> repository-> EF-> Db

Comment: The thing is that switching adapters like that is likely going to have a consequential effect on how queries need to be constructed anyways. If that's truly your goal, then you want your app to depend on methods like `layer.GetSomeSpecificThing()`, not `layer.Get(someQuery, includeSomeStuff, moreLogic)`. That will be infinitely more maintainable and adaptable.

Comment: Yes you are right, Business logic will include many specific methods and combine work with repositories into one particular method. And how would you advise to create an access to data over the EF?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Your data layer should directly interact with EF or whatever. It's the data layer, so it's perfectly acceptable and even *best* if it directly works with the underlying adapter. If that adapter changes, this code will need to change anyways. Your application then depends only on the data layer.

Comment: I understand this, this means using a classic generic repository that provides IQuereble to the outside. And the client directly (for example through the DI) uses the repository wrapper. I wanted to make a layer of business logic, because often have to do the same requests and pull dependent data, I wanted to take these actions into business logic, which is provided by IEnumerable. And all the work with context and  IQueryable are hidden from the client.

Comment: I guess the point I'm making is that you don't need a business layer *and* a data layer. If that business logic is database access logic, then it's the same thing and should all exist in one place. We all love our onion architecture, but it's very easy to go overboard as well. Some abstraction is good, but abstraction just for the sake of abstraction actually hurts your application's maintainability.

Comment: I agree, I used many different approaches and not one did not solve all the problems. I understand you recommend to directly use the adapter EF in the client code without any wrappers well or a lightweight repository to run unit tests.